# OS X Terminal: Meta key + alt functionality at the same time

Tags: macos, emacs, keyboard, terminal

Is there a way to use an <kbd>alt</kbd> / <kbd>option</kbd> key as a meta key but still be able to use it to make some characters which need it?

For example, in my local keyboard layout:

- `@` is <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>
- `\` is <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>
- `|` is <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>
- etc.

So, if I set <kbd>alt</kbd> as a meta key, I can't make those characters anymore. On the other hand, using "press esc, release esc, press a key" to make meta key sequences makes my hands hurt.

Any Emacs users with international keyboards who have solved this, please give any tips you might have! :)

**Edit:**

It appears that I can set <kbd>alt</kbd> as a meta key and then add these kind of settings in inputrc: `"\e2": "@"` This works in the bash shell but it still won't work with Emacs though, so no good.

Comment: This seems to have been solved neatly in this answer by using the right <kbd>alt</kbd> for special characters: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12087/emacs-on-mac-os-x-to-alt-or-command

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Think about using a full featured Emacs for Mac OS X.  I use Carbon Emacs but I believe others (say Aqua Emacs or X11 Emacs) would do the trick.

If you insist on using Emacs in a terminal you can use the `C-x 8` prefix as a compose key.  Try `C-x 8 C-h` to get a list of possibilities.

See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS

Comment: Unfortunately Carbon emacs doesn't fix my problem. I'm still not able to make there characters "@ \  | " while having a functional meta key.

It seems that emacs is just incompatible with international keyboards on mac unless I completely remap the keyboard. I'm already thinking of learning vim ;).

Comment: Mmm, that’s strange.  Here Carbon Emacs does not use the Alt key but the Cmd key as meta.  Is there a particular reason Cmd is not suitable as a meta for you?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that it uses Cmd as meta key. I tried it now, and it works. :)

Comment: BTW, Give Cocoa emacs a try instead.

Comment: @Slomojo: I now use Cocoa Emacs and it is great indeed.

Answer (score 26):

I use a Swedish keyboard in Mac OS X and use the following setup for Emacs.app:

First I have [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html) installed and I have it setup to change the left Option key to Command.

I then have the following in my .emacs:

```
(setq mac-option-modifier 'none)
(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)
```

This makes Emacs treat command as Meta and ignore Option. Since the left Alt/Option key is remapped to command, this makes it work lite meta while the right Alt/Option key still works for entering special characters like @ [] and {}.

App specific Mac shortcuts like Cmd+C and Cmd+V no longer work, but global shortcuts like Cmd+space for Spotlight and Cmd+Tab for app switching do.

**Update:**
If you use [iTerm2](http://sites.google.com/site/iterm2home/) as a Terminal, that has support for mapping only the left Alt/Option key to meta, which means you can still use the right AltGr/Option key for entering special characters. This also means you can use meta as normal inside Emacs running in the iTerm2 terminal.

Comment: For the record, if you don't want to remap with KeyRemap4MacBook, you can use:                                                               (setq mac-option-key-is-meta t)
(setq mac-right-option-modifier nil)                                                                    which will remap left alt key with META and the right alt key with ALT. See http://emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsApp

Comment: Thanks for the iTerm2 hint. It makes a real difference.

Answer (score 14):

I have a Swedish keyboard on my Mac and I'm using Aquamacs. Adding the two lines (attribution goes to Joakim Hårsman)

```
(setq mac-option-modifier 'none)
(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)
```

in `.emacs` (and restarting Aquamacs) did the trick for me.

Comment: Extremely helpful answer, I can't believe why this hasn't got more upvotes. I've been searching for this for an hour now, thank you very much.

Answer (score 12):

with [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/) you can map the left option key to ESC/meta and leave the mapping of the right option key to "normal". This way you can use the right option key to type accents etc.

[image: iTerm2 preferences]

Answer (score 5):

Two work-arounds I use:

- I use xterm running under X11.app. X11.app uses the command key as meta.
- When running emacs in Terminal.app, I just use the rfc1345 input-method, which allows me to enter all kinds of crazy non-ascii characters without needing an option key.

Answer (score 5):

Check out cmd-key-happy.  This little app has worked wonders for me.  It allows you to use command as meta, with exceptions that you can configure.

Author's info follows:

This program allows you to swap the command and alt (or option) keys
in any application, but in particular Terminal.app.

http://github.com/aim-stuff/cmd-key-happy

Answer (score 5):

This is an old post but adding an alternatives for Robots to find.
I borrowed a couple of files from Aquamacs(*emulate-mac-keyboard-mode.el, aquamacs-tools.el*) that fixes the problem (I have a Italian-Pro keyboard) :

```
(defun aq-binding (any)
 nil)
(load  "~/.emacs.d/emulate-mac-keyboard-mode.el") ;;  'noerror
```

this provides:

- few minor modes (***emulate-mac-italian-keyboard-mode,
  emulate-mac-french-keyboard-mode,
  mulate-mac-swiss-german-keyboard-mode,*** etc)
- a menu to play with all the options provided by Aquamacs

Tested with Emacs-23.3-universal-10.6.6 and seems to work ok for me.

Thanks Aquamacs for this, what about pushing this upstream if not already done.

Answer (score 4):

### Special keyboard layout with option deadkey

My solution to this problem is a special keyboard layout I have written, [U.S. custom](http://uscustom.sf.net/). It provides an option [deadkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) that produces option combos without having to use the physical <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> modifier key. For instance, the character ⟨ç⟩ is produced as follows on a normal U.S. keyboard layout:

- Hit <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

The *U.S. custom* keyboard layout adds a second way of producing ⟨ç⟩:

- Hit <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>§</kbd> (the option deadkey), then release it, then hit <kbd>c</kbd>.

This works even in Terminal.app when *Use option as meta key* has been checked.

Note that the U.S. custom keyboard layout does two additional things:

1. It converts plain <kbd>§</kbd> into a <kbd>⎄ Compose</kbd> key (so you could also produce ⟨ç⟩ by hitting <kbd>§</kbd>, then <kbd>,</kbd>, then <kbd>c</kbd>).
2. It replaces the CapsLock mapping by a (significantly extended) *U.S. Extended* keyboard layout.

### Remap option deadkey to right option modifier key

If you have a physical ANSI keyboard, then you lack the <kbd>§</kbd> key. In that case, I recommend assigning the <kbd>§</kbd> key to some other key, for instance to the right <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> modifier key. Install [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/), open `~/Library/Application\ Support/KeyRemap4MacBook/private.xml` and paste the following code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<item>
  <name>Send ISO Section for right Option</name>
  <identifier>private.send_iso_section_for_right_option</identifier>
  <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::OPTION_R, KeyCode::UK_SECTION</autogen>
</item>
<item>
  <name>Send Shift+ISO Section for Shift+right Option (keep normal right Option without Shift)</name>
  <identifier>private.send_shift_iso_section_for_shift_right_option</identifier>
  <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::OPTION_R, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R, KeyCode::UK_SECTION, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
  <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::OPTION_R, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::UK_SECTION, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
</item>
</root>
```

Then, open the KeyRemap4MacBook preference pane, hit *ReloadXML* and then select “Send ISO Section for right option”. Now, your <kbd>⌥ Right Option</kbd> key is remapped to <kbd>§</kbd>, so while the *U.S. custom* keyboard layout is active, hitting <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ Right Option</kbd> will give you the option deadkey state (hitting <kbd>⌥ Right Option</kbd> without additional modifiers will give you a deadkey state equivalent to the option modifier.

If want to keep <kbd>⌥ Right Option</kbd> when <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> is not pressed (instead of the <kbd>⎄ Compose</kbd> key), then select “Send Shift+ISO Section for Shift+right Option (keep normal right Option without Shift)” in the KeyRemap4MacBook preference pane (instead of “Send ISO Section for right Option”). Like that, only <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ Right Option</kbd> will produce the option deadkey, while plain <kbd>⌥ Right Option</kbd> will continue to work as an option modifier. You can even continue using <kbd>⌥ Right Option</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> modifier combos (for instance <kbd>⌥ Right Option</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>→⟨Ç⟩) as long as you don’t hit <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> first.

Answer (score 4):

It's worth thinking about the assumption behind the question. I mean to say that the real problem is making the characters that currently seem to need the option key. This problem can be solved without achieving simultaneous 'meta key + alt functionality'.

Let me explain: I have a similar problem. On my UK keyboard, shift-3 is mapped to the pound sign, £, which means that I generally need to hit option-3 to get the very useful # - a real problem in Terminal, where I use option as meta. However, I find most of the above solutions to be a little over-the-top. I don't want to change to another version of Emacs (eg. Aquamacs), to switch to a different Terminal application (eg. iTerm or xterm), or to install a key-remapping application (eg. KeyRemap4MacBook) all for the sake of one symbol! Perhaps that would suit some people, but I thought it was worth pointing out that if the problem is just one character, it can be solved with a nine-character text file.

With regard to my personal version of this problem, I find the simplest solution is to create a file called `.inputrc` in my home directory, consisting of the following single line:

```
"§": "#"
```

This re-maps the (to me, quite useless) § that can be found to the left of the 1 on the current Mac keyboard to the (almost indispensable) #. That suits me even better than the default setup, because I can now get # with a single keypress. If there were any other characters I needed to remap, it would just be a matter of adding an extra line for each one.

Anyway, that deals with how to get the missing character in the shell, but if you also want it in Emacs (which you didn't say but is probably the case) then you can add something like this to your `.emacs` file (where 35 is the ASCII for the character I happen to want, ie. #):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "§") 'insert-hash)
(defun insert-hash ()
  (interactive)
  (insert 35))
```

It might not be such a neat solution if there were dozens of characters that I routinely wanted to access via the option key, but there aren't.

I hope this helps somebody. As a mere weekend hacker, I ordinarily wouldn't dare post an answer to a question on Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 3):

The above answers mention ways to enter non-ascii input, but that's not really the problem here. The C-x 8 method lets you enter a bunch of non-ascii, but the problem is that you need the option key on mac just to enter the (ascii) character `|' (vertical bar)!

So how do you then enter stuff like M-| (region to shell command) when running emacs in ssh under Terminal.app? No way for it but to use the escape key, since | is option-7 and Terminal.app for some stupid reason won't let you use Cmc as meta :-(

(If anyone knows of a hack (SIMBL perhaps?) that actually does let Terminal.app use Cmd as meta, I'd be very grateful...)

Answer (score 3):

The following solution works, is **UNOBTRUSIVE** and you **don't need iTerm2** or **Aquamacs** or whatever.

## Step 1

Keep "Use option as meta key" turned **ON** in the Terminal.app Settings.

## Step 2

Edit `~/.inputrc` (*make it if it doesn't exist already*), add the following line:

`"\e3": '#'`

This will remap <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> so that you produce a `#` character **as expected in the terminal**, instead of it annoyingly coming back with the prompt `(arg: 3)`.

## Step 3

Edit `~/.emacs`, add the following line:

`(global-set-key (kbd "M-3") "#")`

This will remap <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> so that you produce a `#` character **as expected inside emacs**, instead of it annoyingly doing nothing.

---

**Caveat 1**, This is just **1** re-map. So <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd> + <kbd>**?**</kbd> (*other keys*) won't be remapped, e.g. you may wish to remap <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> to produce the tilde key `~`. Simply follow the same steps outlined above obviously switching <kbd>3</kbd> with whichever key you need going forward.

**Caveat 2,** When you `ssh` into another box, you will face the same difficulties, but all you have to do there is edit the `~/.inputrc` and `~/.emacs` files on that box.

**Caveat 3,** I'm British, on a British MacBook. So I can't vouch for foreign MacBooks.

Answer (score 2):

[Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/) supports that, at least for my (french) keyboard. Once Aquamacs is installed (via drag'n'drop), you can go to Options -> Option, Command, Meta keys and choose an appropriate setting for your keyboard (in my case, ...Meta & French). I am not proficient with Emacs, but all the useful combinations I have tried seem to work ([, {, |, and so forth).

Supported keyboards, according to the menu items as of version 2.1, are :

- British
- US
- Swiss-french
- Swiss-german
- Finnish
- Italian-Pro
- Italian
- Spanish
- French
- German

I would guess the Aquamacs team would be grateful for any contribution, though, should your keyboard not appear in the list.

Comment: I edited the file /Applications//Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/aquamacs/macosx/emulate-mac-keyboard-mode.el directly, adding the right mappings for a Swedish keyboard. It is quite easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

I bit the grass and started hitting the escape key instead. You get use to it...

Comment: I really support this approach but with the new touch bar it's no option for me to do so..

Answer (score 1):

I would like to mod this question up or something because i also use a Swedish keyboard where i must press alt+7 or alt+shift+7 to make | and \ respectively.

I also use Irssi in Terminal.app and these don't mix well.

I'm a long time vim user though so emacs is not an issue to me.

Isn't there some way to remap CMD to be Meta in Terminal.app?

So far i've been surviving by simply typing /wg N in Irssi because having those characters in my Terminal is much more important than IRC.

A solution would be worth gold to me though! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is years late, but for people coming across this page whilst searching for a solution, as I did, I have decided to build one myself, one that doesn't require abandoning Terminal.app in favour of iTerm 2.

It is a simple status bar app that runs in the background and rewrites all left-Alt + $KEY key events to two key events in rapid succession, Esc, then $KEY; however, it only does this if Terminal.app is the focused application.

You can find it here at https://github.com/habibalamin/Metalt.

Answer (score 0):

I assigned escape to the caps lock key and it works quite good. You can configure it easily in the mac system preferences > keyboard > modifier keys.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/282092/236382