# Emacs in Mac OS Lion terminal - map right command key to meta

Tags: emacs, osx-lion

I just started using GNU Emacs on my Mac OS X Lion and I am trying to ease up my hand movement through various key bindings. Specifically, I want to be able to use the right command key  for meta. 
The following code in my .emacs file does the trick for the standalone application (Emacs.app)

```
;;; cmd key for meta
(setq mac-option-key-is-meta nil
mac-command-key-is-meta t
mac-command-modifier 'meta
mac-option-modifier 'none)
```

(Snippet taken from this Superuser [answer](https://superuser.com/a/297452))

but does not work with emacs run in terminal mode. The meta there is still the alt/option key which I set from the Terminal.app preferences. When I disable this option key, I lose the meta key capability all together.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be [keyremap4macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html) that may save you some time if you must use emacs in terminal.  I can take no credit for this, but this [guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3399254/156561) can

Comment: One question though, does keyremap4macbook differentiate between left and right command?

Comment: Nevermind, I just checked the documentation and it looks like I can. This way I will map the right command to meta and keep the left command for copy/pasting and co. Thank you.

Comment: I thought it said something in that website, but I don't know. On terminal it's what, emacs 22.1.1. I prefer 24 and since I'm on OS X I use 24.

Comment: Can i ask why you use emacs in terminal? I've aliased mine so that it opens the file in a real window with the emacs gui version (i.e., 24) on the old Lion machine. Can link if you care.

Comment: I use that version too, just run it with a -nw.

Comment: Oh I am actually in the middle of a self-debate about where I should use Emacs. I am fairly new to it, but I really like how it looks in the terminal (Being a beginner, I cant think of a more sophisticated reason). Do you have some suggestions to help decide? Or issues I might face in the future if I opt for the terminal mode?

Comment: well we both have macs with awesome displays, it's kinda ghetto to use the terminal... even though that is all we really need. I find you get better colour and font support when using http://emacsformacosx.com/builds using a pretest 24 or a nightlie version. Hell, use my dot emacs file and win, buddy! https://github.com/pjammer/emacs_for_rails_devs

Answer (score 2):

i'm not aware of terminal providing you with the ability to deal with the left/right command key mappings.  iterm2 provides the means to accomplish what you're looking for there.  albeit at a global basis for iterm2.