# OSX Option/Alt as Meta: Is there a way to port or use emulate-mac-keyboard-mode in standard Emacs 24?

Tags: macos, emacs, aquamacs

Emacs 24.1 was just released, and I once again feel inclined to use the "real" Emacs (Cocoa GUI version, from http://emacsformacosx.com) instead of Aquamacs. The only thing keeping me in Aquamacs is [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MetaKeyProblems):

> In AquamacsEmacs, Option (Alt) is mapped to Meta - however, because
>   Option is used to input a lot of non-ASCII characters such as ü or £
>   on a variety of keyboards, the special character input methods take
>   precedence by default. You can deselect “Option key produces only
>   special characters” in the Options menu to use Option as Meta, or you
>   set the variable mac-command-modifier to ‘meta - you will lose
>   functionality, of course. If you use a non-English keybboard layout,
>   the emulation modes might be just what you want. While they leave the
>   Option key mapped to Meta, they will allow you to input many common
>   characters ([,],{,},\, etc.) directly with the Option key, just as you
>   would otherwise. You can find them in the Options → Option Key menu -
>   or use, e.g., M-x emulate-mac-german-keyboard-mode.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500602/os-x-terminal-meta-key-alt-functionality-at-the-same-time) speaks about the same issue, and one of the answers is "use Aquamacs".

So in Aquamacs, I can use Option key as Meta and everything is fine, I can type e.g. [ with option(alt)-8 and still use alt as meta when I add this into my .emacs:

```
(setq emulate-mac-finnish-keyboard-mode t)
```

But is there any way to use this feature in Emacs 24? Has anyone ever tried porting emulate-mac-‌​keyboard-mode.el to standard Emacs?

*And no, cmd as meta is not an option for me.*

Comment: Emacs 2.4 !!! I'm already using Emacs 23.4 :-)

Comment: Damn, thanks for pointing that out. I quess version numbers this high do not fit into my brain :)

Answer (score 2):

> Has anyone ever tried porting emulate-mac-‌​keyboard-mode.el to
>   standard Emacs?

I haven't tested it, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7284152/606705) to the question you linked claims to have done just that.

Comment: Thanks! So it seems, I didn't read the answers thoroughly. The main file has this disclaimer: "do not copy / redistribute outside of Aquamacs. All rights reserved" [ https://github.com/davidswelt/aquamacs-emacs/blob/master/aquamacs/src/site-lisp/macosx/emulate-mac-keyboard-mode.el ] Seems weird in a GPL software, Aquamacs is certainly a derivative of Emacs.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick! It would be nice to be able to share or contribute it, but that copyright notice doesn't seem to allow it. A violation of GPL?

Comment: You could try contacting the Aquamacs maintainers for clarification, to see if they can justify that copyright notice. Then it would indeed be nice to share it (you could put it on [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/) if pushing it upstream proves difficult).

Comment: P.S. Other files in that same Aquamacs folder are GPL licensed, so perhaps it was a mistake.

Comment: David Reitter answered. He said that the copyright statement is there on purpose to prevent it from being distributed outside Aquamacs.

Comment: @auramo: how did he justify it in view of GPL?

Comment: He didn't. I contacted FSF and he changed it after apparent pressure.

Answer (score 1):

I am not using Emacs but when I tried to remap certain keys for VIM I had some wired trouble.  I finally found out that these issues were caused by Terminal.app as it somehow did not pass through some key events.  I then switched to iTerm2 which also had some additional features, e.g. X11 mouse events without need for plugins.

Comment: I'm mostly using the GUI-version. In terminal, I just happily use ESC as meta.

Answer (score 1):

I use [EmacsForMacosx](http://emacsformacosx.com/).  This claims to be pure gnu emacs.

The options you are asking for are easily available through `customize-group` `ns`

(from what I know the naming comes from NextStep which kinda was a precessor of OSX)

personally I set the `fn`  key to `meta` as I hardly use it within emacs. And keep `alt` as used by mac. You can also set left and right alternate to different functions - like for german on windows keyboards.

Comment: I don't think you understand the question. To my understanding customize-group just seems to allow me to change e.g. the meta key.

Comment: It's true I don't know to recreate `emulate-mac-finnish-keyboard-mode` (I should have mentioned I tried that feature on Aquamacs for german - but was greatly disappointed as I still had problems achieving special characters as `~`, `{`, ... essential ones if you like to program). Also I have the same problem with german and this solution allows me greater freedom as I can to use ALL special characters achievable with alt.